# Non Clustered index not working

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which has more than 70000 records and if i select top 60 rows it scans the entire **Clustered index** and it takes around 7 to 8 seconds to execute. I have defined Non Clustered index but those are not working Below are the details.

Clustered Index : Id
NON Clustered Index : UserTypeId, LocationId and CityId

```
            SELECT TOP ( 60 )
                    UP.Id AS UserId ,
                    UP.FirstName ,
                    UP.LastName ,
                    UP.City ,
                    UP.ImageURL ,
                    0 AS ActivityCount ,
                    UP.IsPublic ,
                    ISNULL(UP.GemsCount, 0) AS GemsCount ,
                    ISNULL(UP.PointCount, 0) AS PointsCount ,
                    ISNULL(UP.FriendsCount, 0) AS FriendsCount ,
                    FORMAT(UP.LastUpdatedDate, 'MM/d/yyyy HH:m:ss tt','en-US') LastUpdatedDateText,
                    Neighbourhood,
                    UP.UserTypeId,
                    UP.CityId,
                    UP.LocationId

            FROM    UserProfiles AS UP 
            WHERE   
                     UP.UserTypeId = 1
                     AND UP.LocationId > 0
                     AND UP.CityId > 0
            ORDER BY UP.LastUpdatedDate DESC
```

Comment: The query optimizer has determined that -- based on statistics on the tables -- that a full table scan is more efficient than using the other index.  However, 7-8 seconds for this query on 70,000 rows seems like a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is the last part of your query:

```
ORDER BY UP.LastUpdatedDate DESC
```

Either kick that out or add the column to the NC index and you should be fine. As always with this sort of advice it might cause more trouble elsewhere so test it, etcetera.

Comment: It worked i created NC on LastUpdatedDate. Thank you

Comment: Useless advice - as i the example. The problem is not the order by but the where clause. Assuming location and city id are normal id fields the FILTER does not filter anything. The user type id has likely a low cardinality- so the NC index gets ignored (because it does not filter enough) THe moment the locationId and CityId are "real" values - the NC index should STILL be used - with the results then ordered in tempdb. The LastUpdatedDate index that helps now may be totally irrelevant in this case.

Comment: @TomTom whatever, it works according to OP so there must be something to it ;)